# Use excel's "AutoFill" command AT ONCE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about "AutoFill" of EXCEL.

**Table1**
[image]

I would like to use autofill function to change "Table1" to "Table2"(below) AT ONCE.

**Table2**
[image]
I understand I just have to select horizontal cells to copy it to below cells one by one.
But, it must take tons of hours.

I also attached same question on my tweet by attaching videos.
https://twitter.com/FA_inox/status/1625065500882636800?s=20&t=Fa2jHll2I9dWrVTHiqJrmA

Please give me answers or hints when you have time. m(^^)m

So far, I have no idea to AutoFill copy at once.
I don't feel like to spend many hours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine I want to `AutoFill` the following sheet up to last row which is filled in:

[image]

I select all cells up to the last filled row, press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, "Special", "Blanks".
Then I press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or I click in the formula bar) and I type `=A1`. I enter that formula using <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd>.
This is what I get:

[image]

You can easily record this into a macro:

```
Sub Macro3()
  Range("A1:A14").Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

Or, shorter:

```
Sub Macro3()
  Range("A1:A14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

Why did you say it must take tons of hours? :-)

Comment: Sir Dominique, 
 It works for my computer too, and I now shorten the duration of my analysis substantially!! :-)
Really Thanks!! I appreciate you!!

Comment: @Mikuinox: Glad I could help. If my answer is useful or even solves your issue, please upvote and/or accept it (this is how this site works).

Comment: I've done it, and thank you for introducing how this website works!